# reopen write stream after passing stream.end()

Tags: node.js, stream, node.js-stream, node-streams

Is it possible reopen a closed stream after calling stream.end()?

My requirement is to use streams to write in chunks and the whole process is called inside a scheduler, so once the stream is closed and the next time scheduler is called the said error is emitted which is really undesirable.

And also I don't want to create a new stream every time the scheduler runs.

[Node.js Stream's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) says

> Calling the stream.write() method after calling stream.end() will
>   raise an error.

Comment: If you still have things to write to the stream, why do you close it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am closing it for that iteration, when scheduler runs again I need it to be open again. How else could I listen to finish event of stream?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no, this isn't possible. Once a stream is closed, it is closed.

Comment: Does that mean I have to create a new stream everytime scheduler runs? Also do you know if it is possible to emulate finish event without sending stream.end()?

Comment: yes, this is js bro :))